# Discord.JS Replying into Embed

Tags: discord, discord.js

I am trying to make when they write in a specific channel, it deletes their comment, and the bot will take this and reply inside the embed, but I am very struggling.

```
client.on("message", message => {

  const args = message.content.slice(prefix.length).split(/ +/);
  const command = args.shift().toLowerCase();

  if (message.channel.id == `635991288971326568`) {
    if (message.author.bot) return;
    message.delete();
    //message.channel.send(`**${message.author}**`);

    const newEmbed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
      .setColor("#ff0000")
      .setTitle("Αποθήκη ΕΚΑΒ")
      .setURL("")
      .setDescription(`**Doctor:** ${message.author}\n**Current Date:** ${new Date().toLocaleString()}\n**Removed:** ${(message.reply())}`)
      .setThumbnail("")
      .setImage("")
      .setFooter("Created and Developed by InNovAqua#0666 ❤️");

    message.channel.send(newEmbed);

    message.channel.send(message.content);
  }
});
```

Comment: Please explain you problem. Is it not sending the embed? Or is it not deleting the message? Or any error in console?

Comment: @Radnerus when I write anything, it deletes, replies with [object Promise] instead of the message, the guy sent and in terminal is shows:

(node:236) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: DiscordAPIError: Cannot send an empty message

Comment: Ok, so `message.content` will become null after deleting the message. so message.content will return `empty message` when you are trying to send. Store the message content before deleting it.

Comment: @Radnerus and how to store it? in a string like const string = ${message.content} ?

Comment: Without the template literals(${}). Just `const string = message.content`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will remove the message a user sends in a channel that you have chosen and send it in the embed:

```
client.on("message", message => {
  
    const args = message.content.slice(prefix.length).split(/ +/);
    const command = args.shift().toLowerCase();
    const messagesent = message.content
  
    if(message.channel.id == `808453136817324084`){
    if(message.author.bot)return;
  message.delete();
  //message.channel.send(`**${message.author}**`);
  
  const newEmbed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
          .setColor("#ff0000")
          .setTitle("Αποθήκη ΕΚΑΒ")
          .setURL("")
          .setDescription(`**Doctor:** ${message.author}\n**Current Date:** ${new Date().toLocaleString()}\n**Removed:** ${(messagesent)}`)
          .setThumbnail("")
          .setImage("")
          .setFooter("Created and Developed by InNovAqua#0666 ❤️");
          
          message.channel.send(newEmbed);
  }
  });
```

If you want you can make the bot also send the message with out having it in the embed you can do that with:

```
client.on("message", message => {
  
    const args = message.content.slice(prefix.length).split(/ +/);
    const command = args.shift().toLowerCase();
    const messagesent = message.content
  
    if(message.channel.id == `808453136817324084`){
    if(message.author.bot)return;
  message.delete();
  //message.channel.send(`**${message.author}**`);
  
  const newEmbed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
          .setColor("#ff0000")
          .setTitle("Αποθήκη ΕΚΑΒ")
          .setURL("")
          .setDescription(`**Doctor:** ${message.author}\n**Current Date:** ${new Date().toLocaleString()}\n**Removed:** ${(messagesent)}`)
          .setThumbnail("")
          .setImage("")
          .setFooter("Created and Developed by InNovAqua#0666 ❤️");
          
          message.channel.send(newEmbed);
  
  message.channel.send(message.content);
  }
  });
```

This here I have it set up to send the message in the embed and as a regular message.